# iOS App Rejected: Guideline 2.5.4, CoreBluetooth Background Processing

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

My app was **rejected** for TestFlight Beta as follows:

"Guideline 2.5.4 - Performance - Software Requirements

Your app declares support for external-accessory in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file but does not declare any external accessory protocols supported by your app. The external accessory background mode is intended for apps that communicate with hardware accessories through the External Accessory framework.

If your app is meant to work with external hardware, supported protocols must be included in the UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols key in your app's Info.plist file - and the hardware's PPID # should be provided in the Review Notes field of your app in App Store Connect.

Additionally, your app must be authorized by MFi to use the desired hardware. If you are not yet in the MFi Program, you can enroll at MFi program."

---

I read similar questions, but none answer or solve my problem.

In Xcode project settings I have checked "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories" under Background Modes.

In info.plist I have NSBluetoothPeriperalUsageDescription="Uses Bluetooth for switches and adaptive toys".

If I uncheck "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories" under Background modes I think my app will be approved, but it leaves out the following important set of users of the app as follows:

The app is for capability switch users in the Accessibility realm, which is already a small set of users. The feature requiring background communication between the app (central) and switches (peripheral) is for a specific subset of switch users that have a visual impairment and significant cognitive delays. This is an even smaller set of users, probably < 100 in the world, but it is an extremely important use case for these users. It is not practical to have the app always in the foreground when they use the app to use audio to say 1 or 2 words, typically "Yes"/"No", or "I need help!”, needed even when there is no WiFi or cell signal. For example, my test user (downloaded to her app directly from my Xcode dev env) with Fox G1 syndrome uses this mode exclusively and has seen great improvements in having some minimal control of things in her life (e.g., saying “I need help” when she feels a seizure coming on or requires diapering).

Current capability switches on the market use the Bluetooth HID profile, which does not allow for background use or 2-way communication between central (my app) and accessory (switch box), to do important feedback like adjusting delay time for switch activations for users with movement disorders and tremors, also the case of my test user.

Has anyone successfully received app approval for background communication with an accessory as a peripheral that is not MFi or HomeKit approved? When I read the MFi FAQ, this peripheral accessory does not appear to fall into the MFi umbrella, and with HomeKit I already came across the limitation that it does not work when the device is sleeping (this latter case is another bone I have to pick, since non-touch users cannot turn on lights, open auto-doors, turn up heaters... unless the device is open which they cannot physically do, and Siri is not an option since they are non-verbal!).

Additional technical background regarding the app: I use only CoreBluetooth (UART), where the app is the central. My API is so simple I am slightly embarrassed to list it, but here goes:

// BLE UART API

let receiveSwitch1On: NSString = "SWITCH1_ON"

let receiveSwitch1Off: NSString = "SWITCH1_OFF"

let receiveSwitch2On: NSString = "SWITCH2_ON"

let receiveSwitch2Off: NSString = "SWITCH2_OFF"

let sendSwitchboxOn: NSString = "ON"

let sendSwitchboxOff: NSString = "OFF"

let updateDebouncePrefix: NSString = "DEBOUNCE="

let updateGraceOffPrefix: NSString = "GRACE_OFF=“

Does anyone have a suggestion on what I could change technically, or advice for navigating the app approval process on what my lowest cost option would be to keep this use case of background comm between app and peripheral? Already I've spent significant time and money to create this capability. I am not in this to make money, but to provide some benefit to a small set of users that are largely left out of technology. I am willing to spend more time and money to reach the finish line, but I really can't afford a lot of ongoing program costs as I expect MFi or HomeKit might be.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Check your info plist. Apple's message says that you have external accessory background capability selected.  This is not the Bluetooth LE background mode you are discussing in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I made the change and everything works the way I want it to. I resubmitted the app for approval and will report the outcome here.

Comment: Following up again since removing the external accessory background capability key from info plist and resubmitting... The app was approved, so this was the problem. Thank you very much. I am not sure how to make your comment the answer, or if I summarize in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your info plist.

Apple's message says that you have external accessory background capability selected. This is not the Bluetooth LE background mode you are discussing in your question.

You don't need external accessory capability to use Core Bluetooth in the background.